# Setting the text of a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

I'm using the new Xcode beta (which might be where the issue is coming from).

I followed an online tutorial, with making a simple counter app.

The issue I have is with the line that is followed below:

```
outputlabel.text = "The button has been clicked \ (currentcount) number of times"
```

The whole code is as followed:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
     var currentcount = 0

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     @IBAction func addOneButton(sender: UIButton) {

        currentcount = currentcount + 1
        outputlabel.text  = "The button has been clicked \(currentcount) number of times"
        outputLabel.textColor = UIColor.redColor() 
    }
```

The issue is:

> use of unresolved identifier `outputlabel`

Why can't my code find `outputlabel`?

Comment: Can you please include some source code, like the file in which the error is showing up?

Comment: That means `outputlabel` is a variable not declared anywhere in the execution scope. Please show the complete class

Answer (score 3):

It must be something like this,

```
let outputlabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30))
outputlabel.text = "The button has been clicked \(currentcount) number of times"
```

You are actually missing declaration of your label.

OR

If you are using it via @IBOutlet, make sure you have connected `outputlabel` in NIB/Storyboard file.

OR

Recheck your declaration, it might be different like `outputLabel` and you are using it as `outputlabel`.

Comment: Doubtful; it's more likely to be an`@IBOutlet` instance variable.

Comment: @Droppy He might be missing connection to Outlet.

Comment: @Droppy is right.  The error just tells us that the variable has not been declared, whether it's an IBOutlet or not...props to you for answering this question with so little context.

Comment: @MichaelPhillips Edit your question and remove these comments.

Comment: @MichaelPhillips you are using 'outputlabel' and declaring it as 'outputLabel`. Fix it and you are done.

Comment: @RoNiT Thank you so much! I cant believe it was something so simple as a capital letter ruining it!

Answer (score 0):

Swift 2.0:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let labelName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 200))
  labelName.text = "Sample Label"

  // Enum type, two variations:
  labelName.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
  labelName.textAlignment = .Right

  labelName.textColor = UIColor.redColor()
  labelName.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor()
  labelName.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: CGFloat(22))
  self.view.addSubview(labelName)

 }
```